# Jquery - input range locked when i apply event change

Tags: jquery

I have a html form with a range field, in the change event, i have this:

```
$("#slider-customer-type").on("change", function() {
    if($("#slider-customer-type").val()==0) {
        $("#partial-customertype-business").removeClass("show");
        $("#partial-customertype-business").addClass("hide");
        $("#partial-customertype-personal").addClass("show");
    } else {
        $("#partial-customertype-personal").removeClass("show");
        $("#partial-customertype-personal").addClass("hide");
        $("#partial-customertype-business").addClass("show");
    }
});
```

if range value is 0, i shown a html form but if the range value is 1, shown another html form.

The problem is, if i added the next code, the range field not working and stay locked. wneh i change the value range field, i want to empty all input fields forms.

```
$("#slider-customer-type").on("change", function() {
    if($("#slider-customer-type").val()==0) {
        $("#partial-customertype-business").removeClass("show");
        $("#partial-customertype-business").addClass("hide");
        $("#partial-customertype-personal").addClass("show");
    } else {
        $("#partial-customertype-personal").removeClass("show");
        $("#partial-customertype-personal").addClass("hide");
        $("#partial-customertype-business").addClass("show");
    }
    $("#myform :input").prop("value", '');
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: Dont set the `value` attribute - use the `.val()` function: `$("#myform :input").val("");`

Comment: i am testing your proposal, but not working, the input range field is locked. I am using $("#myform :input").val(""); but not working. if i click in value 2 working ok, but value 1 is input range locked..

Comment: Any errors in console? Got a Fiddle to test with?

Comment: Took a stab that you might be using something like JQuery UI. If so, here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/vunh79v0/1/